# Apache - Automatically redirect to maintenance page when backend server goes down

Tags: apache, weblogic

I am trying to find a solution to Automatically redirect Apache to maintenance page when the backend application server goes down.

I have manual solution (RewriteCond) in place when the backend WebLogic server is shutdown for patching/deployment, I add the RewriteCond in the Apache configuration file. This manual method is working fine.

I also tried the .htaccess with

ErrorDocument 500 /maintenance/MaintenancePage.html

ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance/MaintenancePage.html

ErrorDocument 401 /maintenance/PortalMaintenancePage.html

ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance/PortalMaintenancePage.html

But Apache does not redirect to maintenance page with the above ErrorDocument when the weblogic server is down.

Apache show the following error when WebLogic is shutdown -

Failure of Web Server bridge:
No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds or idempotent set to OFF or method not idempotent.

Is there any way to tell Apache to AUTOMATICALLY redirect to maintenance page when the backend application or the WebLogic server is down.

I welcome any other solutions or alternatives to address this issue.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ErrorPage parameter in the WebLogic Web Server Plugin to redirect to the desired page.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/plugin_params.htm#PLGWL473